# Retrieve Webpart Proprties through CSOM in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, csom

My goal is to get an export of all webpart properties (including custom props) along with their values, from a page (urls provided through CSV).

I am following this approach:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/retrieve-webparts-from-page-using-csom-with-powershell-for-s/

I am able to access all webparts sitting on a page as I can print their ID and Name, but getting an error in:

```
$ctx.Load($webpart.WebPart.Properties)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Error:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Field or property "Properties" does not exist."
```

Appreciate your inputs / thoughts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 CSOM library didn't have the property "$webpart.WebPart.Proerties", if you can access the SharePoint Server, use SharePoint Server Object Model in PowerShell instead:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$SiteUrl = "http://www.yoursite.com"
$pageURL = "Pages/default.aspx"

$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($SiteUrl)
$psite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingSite($site)
$web = Get-SPWeb $SiteUrl
$pweb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)

$wpm = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($pageURL, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

#List all the web parts
$wpm.WebParts | ft

#Get the details of the first web part
$wp = $wpm.WebParts[0]
$wp
```

Comment: Thanks @Jerry_MSFT, unfortunately I dont have access to the SP servers! Not sure if installing SP2010 binaries in one of the VMs would help?

Comment: Server Object Model PowerShell need to use in the server where SharePoint installed, other VMS won't work. A workaround is to create custom web service with Server Object Model and then call the web service remotely to load web part properties.